# Proof of the weak law of large numbers by Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables which are defined
on the same sample space $\Omega$.

Using Chebyshev’s inequality, or otherwise, prove the weak law of large numbers as it pertains to a sequence of identically distributed random variables 
{$X_n$} for $n=1,...,\infty$ each having finite mean=$μ$ and finite variance=$σ^2$.

I'm totally lost as to how to go about proving this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the sequence also has to be independent.

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Define $\bar X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$. It is easy to verify that $\mathbb E\bar X=\mu$ and $\mathbb V\bar X=\sigma^2/n$. By Chebyshev's inequality, for any $k>0$ it holds that $\Pr[|\bar X-\mu|>k\sigma]\leq \frac{1}{k^2n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus $\bar X\overset{p}{\to} \mu$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you have $\frac{1}{k^2 "n"}$ please?

Comment: Because the inequality is followed from the Chebyshev's Inequality, and in the nominator, you have $E(|\bar{(X_n)} - \mu|^2)$ which equals to $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, so the n now becomes part of the denominator, and the $\sigma^2$ in the nominator cancels with the $\sigma^2$ in the denominator.